# How to check if two fields in row are identical and create another variable based on that in R

Tags: r

I have a data set with fields user_country and advertiser_country. 
I would like to create another variable which would say "local" if user_country matches advertiser_country or "not_local" if this isn't the case.

What is the best way to do that?

I tried something like that, but it didn't work:

```
with(dataset2, dataset2$local_country <- if (identical(user_country,advertiser_country)) "local" else "not_local")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a vector with the possible values and use the value returned by the comparison (+ 1) as an index.

```
dataset2 <- transform(dataset2, 
                      local_country = c("not_local", 
                                        "local")[(user_country == 
                                                    advertiser_country) + 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ifelse` paradigm:

```
dataset2$local_country = ifelse(dataset2$user_country==dataset2$advertiser_country, "local","not_local")
```

This will evaluate every element in the array resulting from your `==` call and return "local" if true, else "not_local". `identical` only tests for complete objects so unless everything is local, it will return a single "FALSE".

Here is the code with a generated frame:

```
dataset2 = data.frame("user_country"=sample(letters,100,replace=T),"advertiser_country"=sample(letters[1:10],100,replace=T),stringsAsFactors=F)
dataset2$local_country = with(dataset2,ifelse(user_country==advertiser_country, "local","not_local"))
```

Comment: As an fyi: use `dput(sample_data)` when you post, it is easier to check that it works.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand comment about sample_data? I'm very new to R:(

Comment: Also, i got an error:

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "local", value = logical(0)) :
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 715
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'

Comment: in R type in `dput(head(dataset2,10))` and add the output to your initial question. Also helps to put `str(dataset2)` there. It will give people an idea of how your data is set up.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used was given to me by work colleague:

I slightly changed the variable, I decided to create is_local with TRUE and FALSE values as per his suggestion

```
dataset2$user_country <- as.character(dataset2$user_country)
dataset2$advertiser_country <- as.character(dataset2$advertiser_country)

dataset2$is_local <- FALSE
dataset2[dataset2$advertiser_country == dataset2$user_country,]$local <- TRUE
```

Comment: You don't need to initilaize the new variable with `FALSE`s. The command `dataset2$local <- dataset2$advertiser_country == dataset2$user_country` is sufficient.